# How can I register a custom HqlTranslator in Hibernate 6 (Spring Boot 3)

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, configuration, hibernate-6.x

**Problem**

I recently switched to Hibernate 6. Now I encounter this exception, if a query is logged which contains a `%` symbol for a `LIKE` clause.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.Integer eu.rentall.application.repository.AgpInternalOrderRepository.resetInternalOrderFromProcessing(java.lang.Long)
>
> at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:100)
>
> Caused by: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '''
>
> at java.base/java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2750)
> at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2671)
> at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2625)
> at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:4143)
> at org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLocationAwareLogger.doLogf(Slf4jLocationAwareLogger.java:81)
> at org.jboss.logging.Logger.logf(Logger.java:2445)
> at org.jboss.logging.DelegatingBasicLogger.debugf(DelegatingBasicLogger.java:344)
> at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:75)
> at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.lambda$interpretHql$2(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:744)
> at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.createHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:141)

I upgraded to Spring Boot 3.1.0 and now also upgraded Hibernate to 6.2.5.Final.

I also use org.slf4j:2.0.7 with org.jboss.logging:3.5.0Final as its implementation.

The log framework is ch.qos.logback:1.4.7.

**Reason**

For query-logging `org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator#translate` is being called.

```
@Override
public <R> SqmStatement<R> translate(String query, Class<R> expectedResultType) {
    HqlLogging.QUERY_LOGGER.debugf( "HQL : " + query );
    ...
}
```

After debugging through all this code I found the problem is the use of `HqlLogging.QUERY_LOGGER.debugf` instead of `HqlLogging.QUERY_LOGGER.debug`.

The difference between those two methods is this line in `org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLocationAwareLogger`:

```
// doLog(..)
final String text = parameters == null || parameters.length == 0 ? String.valueOf(message) : MessageFormat.format(String.valueOf(message), parameters);

// doLogf(..)
final String text = parameters == null ? String.format(format) : String.format(format, parameters);
```

Since StandardHqlTranslator does not provide parameters, parameters is set to the empty array.

Therefore `String.format(format, parameters)` is called which considers `%` a format expression.

**Fix (to be rolled out in Hibernate 6.2.6)**

org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator#translate should be changed to call:

```
HqlLogging.QUERY_LOGGER.debugf( "HQL : %s", query );
```

---

I already reported the problem to Hibernate: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/query-logging-in-hibernate-6-causes-an-exception-when-a-query-contains-a-like-qerry/7861

which resulted in a bug report: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16831

---

**Question**

As a temporary workaround I would like to provide a custom implementation of `org.hibernate.query.hql.HqlTranslator` with the outlined fix.

The `org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryEngineOptions` interface even defines a method:
`HqlTranslator getCustomHqlTranslator();`. `QueryEngineOptions` is extended by `SessionFactoryOptions`.

However I have yet to find a way, to provide those options to Hibernate, so it will use my implementation.

How can I register my custom implementation of `org.hibernate.query.hql.HqlTranslator`?